# how to check logs in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to enable and see logs in mysql workbench.

In my my-default.ini file added log=filename.log.

Saved--->services stopped and started

Now where I can or how can see the actions performed on table in log of mysql ?

Comment: Execute this command SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%log%" which will show you all the log files path for the server. I think you are looking for General Query log?

Comment: @SathishD, Yes something like that. If accidentally some records get deleted from Table A, then how  I'd be able to check the logs for that specific table ?

Comment: You will have those in General query log.

Answer (score 7):

The following image explains what to do. Switch to the admin section and click on the `Server Logs` entry.
[image]

Comment: location of MYSQL configuration file (i.e my.cnf) not specified (Error). How can I fix this ?

Comment: This is a different question. Difficult to answer in a comment, since I cannot add a screenshot. Look in the connection setting under "System Profile". Note: on some platforms the default installation of a MySQL server does not have a config file and uses default values (e.g. on OSX).

Comment: Could you help me for what to write in my-default.ini file so that I could check logs ?  And in describe variables do I need to set path to general_log of my-default.ini ?

Comment: Open a new question at SO instead of hijacking an existing one.

Comment: but all these comments goes to this question only !!

Comment: This question is about the server logs, not the config file and I'm sure there are already questions about how to configure a server using WB on OSX. Just search a bit.

Comment: Searching from last couple of hours, but nothing lit up my problem

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822702/location-of-mysql-configuration-file-ie-my-cnf-not-specified/42277475

Answer (score 1):

The below tells the location and for more info visit https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-configuring-files.html
[image: For the client side logs]

Answer (score 1):

I had to edit the actual xml config file:

...\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\server_instances.xml

changed from:

```
<value type="string" key="logOutput">NONE</value>
```

to:

```
<value type="string" key="logOutput">FILE</value>
```

I can now see the logs.